# applet not cache in client

Tags: java, caching, applet

I have a scanner **applet** with size about 2m and takes too long to load and when I enable console I found this error many times:

```
Cache entry not found 
    [url: 10.32.0.19/digital/script/scanner.jar, version: 1.0.0.0]
```

Then I search and find some questions that not solve my problem.

This is my html:

```
<object classid="java:com.openkm.applet.Scanner" 
            type="application/x-java-applet"
            archive="scanner.jar" 
            codebase="10.32.0.19/script/"
            height="3" width="5"
            name="applet">
        <param name="archive" value= "scanner.jar"/>
        <PARAM NAME="cache_archive" VALUE="scanner.jar">
        <PARAM NAME="cache_version" VALUE="1.0.0.0">
        <param name="mayscript" value="true" />
        <param name="scriptable" value="true" />
        <PARAM name="codebase" value="10.32.0.19/script/">
        <param name="path" value="10.32.0.19/scan/responder"/>
        <param name="token" value="<?php echo $this->sid ?>"/>
        <param name="cotag" value="1">
        <param name="action" value="entery" />
        <param name="lang" value="en_EN" />
        <center>
            <img src="/path/to/images/chemwriter_logo.png" />
            <p><strong>ChemWriter content requires Java 1.4.2 or higher, which your browser does not appear to have.</strong></p>

            <p><a href="http://www.java.com/en/download/index.jsp">Get the latest Java Plug-in.</a></p>
        </center>
    </object>
```

Cache setting in Java preferences is enabled.

I try with Mozilla Firefox 15 on Windows XP.

How to solve this error?

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  Great edit. -- For more reliable caching, launch it using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  The applet could still remain embedded, and JWS resource caching for an embedded applet should still be more reliable than plain applet.  Most likely to be reliable is free floating JWS, but I note this applet calls and is called by JavaScript.  Run time parameters might be specified in the JNLP, of course.  What is the JS interaction used for?

Comment: You mean I can use JWS with JS interation ?

Comment: Only while the applet is embedded.  Not if it is free floating.  Again ***What is the JS interaction used for?***

Comment: Maybe its not really needed. But its make my application more user friendly.

Comment: That's nice, but it still does not answer my question.  *What is the JS interaction used for?"*  And if you say 'friendly stuff', I'm going to scream.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a server configuration issue.

Q: Do you have any control over the server?

Q: Can you modify the "mime-type" of ".jar" files to `application/java-archive`?

Comment: thanks for answer, yes I have my own server, let me see can I modify that

Comment: how can I check mime-type of .jar file?

Comment: If it takes **too long** to load your 2MB applet **over LAN** than something else is probably wrong, **NOT** just the cache settings.

Comment: I change mime-type to application/java-archive but didn't work.

Comment: this is **over Lan** and  about 30 second to load

Comment: *"how can I check mime-type of .jar file?"* I provide a little [MIME Type check](http://pscode.org/mime/).  E.G. the JMF MP3 SPI at my site for [type `application/x-java-archive`](http://pscode.org/mime/applet.html?media.url=http%3A%2F%2Fpscode.org%2Flib%2Fmp3plugin.jar&mime.type=application%2Fx-java-archive).

Comment: If 2MB file takes 30 secs to load (or is it 30 secs to start?) over LAN (100Mb+/sec speed) that means there is something **VERY VERY WRONG** with it. If you need further help we will need further details...

Comment: @MKT: there are at least two issues here: 1) "Cache entry not found", 2) why does it take so long?  I'm *not* convinced the "30 seconds" is necessarily "network delay".  SUGGESTION: install [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) on your PC and take a sniffer trace of the applet download.  Post back if you have any questions how to do this. IMHO...

Answer (score 2):

There is no "probable" here (unless you did not provide correct logs and setup details) - it is sever side problem. Server setup or applet build seems to be incorrect looking for cached version in (what looks like) incorrect and definitely unconfigured directory.